# Allow for the MasterDetail page to have the master on the right in Xamarin.forms

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

is It possible side menu on the right side in master detail and swipe from right to left or left to right using Xamarin.forms.

Answer (score 1):

Have you take a look to this Slider view control.

[SlideOver Kit](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/SlideOverKit/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: was thinking to write my own ,saved me some effort !(+1)

Answer (score 0):

Possible yes ,u need to write your own component !

[This link could be of help](http://www.allenhashkey.com/mobile-development/xamarin-forms-custom-master-detail-rightleft/)

Comment: This link for android not for ios.